# Setup deployment group agent with powershell failed

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I try to run the script provided in “deployment group” section on my Win7 VM (what I do is just “copy\paste\run”).

```
$ErrorActionPreference="Stop";
If(-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() ).IsInRole( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] “Administrator”)){ throw "Run command in an administrator PowerShell prompt"};
If($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt (New-Object System.Version("3.0"))){ throw "The minimum version of Windows PowerShell that is required by the script (3.0) does not match the currently running version of Windows PowerShell." };
If(-NOT (Test-Path $env:SystemDrive\'azagent')){mkdir $env:SystemDrive\'azagent'};
cd $env:SystemDrive\'azagent'; 
for($i=1; $i -lt 100; $i++){$destFolder="A"+$i.ToString();
if(-NOT (Test-Path ($destFolder))){mkdir $destFolder;cd $destFolder;break;}}; 
$agentZip="$PWD\agent.zip";
$DefaultProxy=[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy;$securityProtocol=@();$securityProtocol+=[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol;
$securityProtocol+=[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=$securityProtocol;
$WebClient=New-Object Net.WebClient; 
$Uri='https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.204.0/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.204.0.zip';
if($DefaultProxy -and (-not $DefaultProxy.IsBypassed($Uri))){$WebClient.Proxy= New-Object Net.WebProxy($DefaultProxy.GetProxy($Uri).OriginalString, $True);};
 $WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, $agentZip);
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory( $agentZip, "$PWD");
.\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname "MY_GROUP_NAME" --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url 'https://dev.azure.com/MY_ORG_NAME/' --projectname 'MY_PROJ_NAME';
 Remove-Item $agentZip;
```

And error occurs:

```
em $agentZip;
At line:1 char:179
+ ... Current() ).IsInRole( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] “Adminis ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:180
+ ... nRole( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] “Administrator?){ throw ...
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '“Administrator?' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:180
+ ... nRole( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] “Administrator?){ throw ...
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Missing closing ')' after expression in 'If' statement.
At line:1 char:194
+ ... Role( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] “Administrator?){ throw  ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

Here is the info of powershell version:
[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: seems like a parsing error due to `“` (`[char]8220`) instead of `"` (`[char]34`)

Comment: The command is provided by Azure DevOps, maybe I should modify the script? Or, I have to upgrade\downgrade my powershell version?

Comment: Smart quotes strikes again... It doesn't matter who provided the script. Smart quotes can "infect" code which has been copied into/out of Word documents, or other word processors. They probably don't even know it's happening. Try replacing all the smart quotes with normal ones first.

Comment: Thank you sir! It could be consider as a bug from Azure. After replacing all smart quotes with straight quote, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the question comments, **the issue stems around faulty quotation marks in the provided registration script**.

[image]

It seems to only affect more modern Windows/PowerShell versions, so [it hasn't been addressed by Microsoft with any priority yet](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Script-to-register-agent-in-deployment-g/10061080). For now, the workaround is to find and replace.

**If you paste the script into a text editor**, search for `“Administrator”` and replace with `"Administrator"`.

**If you paste the script into (a modern) PowerShell prompt directly**, the faulty characters will be stripped and you will need to manually add them:
[image]

Comment: in other words, the quotation marks are throwing the error.  replace the quotation marks with yours.  they might not appear on the powershell screen, but you'll see them in notepad.